# No sound, output devices disappeared

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, mute

After installing PulseAudio Equalizer and Lollypop and yes, tweaking the Pulse's config file a bit with not much knowledge, I have lost my audio after a reboot. Output devices have disappeared, Ubuntu is on permanent mute, I have no idea what to do. Help!

System: 16.04 LTS
Laptop: Thinkpad 64-bit
Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-4210M CPU @ 2.60GHz × 4